# In elastic collision, should gravitational potential energy not be considered?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

In elastic collision of two bodies, kinetic energy is conserved, i.e.

$$ \frac{1}{2}m_1u_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2u_2^2 = \frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2 $$

If the two bodies are under the influence of gravity, shouldn't there be gravitational potential energy stored as well ?

Does this equation not considers gravity, or is total K.E still conserved under the influence of gravity before and after collision ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the collision is very slow over a significant path length, we generally consider the gravitational potential energy immediately before the collision to be the same as the potential energy immediately after the collision.  Being equal on both sides of the before and after equation, they cancel.

Answer (score 1):

For the typical collision problem, the force of gravity is negligible during the short duration of the collision; that is, the collision is essentially an impulse problem.  The effect of gravity comes into play after the collision to evaluate the later motion.